# Connecting LINQPAD to azure storage

Tags: c#, linq, azure, linqpad

I would like to connect LINQPAD to my development storage Azure. I understand that I need to use something like the following:

```
var accountName = "jamiekt"; 
var sharedKey = "smXblLn+==";
var uri = new System.Uri("http://table.core.windows.net/");
```

But how can I connect to the local storage emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example of wiring LINQpad to Azure storage is here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/IUnknown/archive/2010/03/10/linqpad-with-azure-table-storage.aspx

Use the development storage accounts as detailed here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/

in particular:

> Account name: devstoreaccount1
>
> Account key:
>   Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==

The URI depends on what you want to connect to:

> The following format is used for addressing resources running in the
>   storage emulator:
>
> Blob Service: `http://127.0.0.1:10000/<account-name>/<resource-path>`
>
> Queue Service: `http://127.0.0.1:10001/<account-name>/<resource-path>`
>
> Table Service: `http://127.0.0.1:10002/<account-name>/<resource-path>`
>
> For example, the following address might be used for accessing a blob
>   in the storage emulator:
>
> `http://127.0.0.1:10000/myaccount/mycontainer/myblob.txt`